# Cardinality "set" property in gremlin is ordered or unordered?

Tags: set, gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3, gremlin-java

Cardinality "set" property in apache tinkerpop gremlin is ordered or unordered?

List is not supported in AWS Neptune, but I need to maintain insertion order (or) save & retrieve the items in specific order.

Answer (score 0):

Tinkerpop doesn't define insertion order for properties in set cardinality. It is totally up to the server implementation to define this.

If you want to get the properties listed in a particular order then I would recommend you to use `order` step explicitly. This will ensure irrespective which server implementation you run your query, the result should always be same.